# Hovering an element with border attribute gets moved

Tags: html, css

When hovering an li-element, I want to add a border at the bottom and the top. The code looks like that:

```
#overview li:hover {
    background: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rwDYR/ (hover the navigation on the left)

The problem is, that it moves the li element for 1 or 2 pixels. I already tried to add a `margin-top: -1px` for the hover state, but that's not solving the problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a transparent border when you're not hovering the `<li>` (and change only the color of the borders on `:hover`)

```
#overview li {
   padding: 5px;
   border-top: 1px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

#overview li:hover {
   border-color: #fff;
   /* other style ... */
}
```

(tested on-the-fly on your fiddle, it seems it works fine)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're adding a border to the `li` when you hover it.  There are a variety of solutions.  One is to decrease the padding by 1 pixel to compensate for the added border.

http://jsfiddle.net/rwDYR/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to add a 1px top margin from the beginning, and setting top margin to 0 on hover, in order to compensate for the 1px top border.
You can also do it by changing the padding (instead of the margin)

Comment: indeed... that confirms my answer

Answer (score 0):

depending on the level of browser support, you could use css `box-sizing` property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

```
#overview li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

updated 
http://jsfiddle.net/rwDYR/5/

or use same background color for border

```
#overview li {

padding: 5px;     
border-top:solid 1px rgb(24, 53, 82);
border-bottom:solid 1px rgb(24, 53, 82); 

}
```